# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I was trying to implement a kind of post feature on my app I bumped into this error which is doing my head.

```
ArgumentError in Projects#show
first argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
```

Micropost controller.

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @micropost = @project.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    @micropost.user.id = current_user.id
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Micropost.model

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :project

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

  validates :user_id , presence: true
  validates :project_id, presence: true
  validate  :picture_size

  #...
end
```

An extract from routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
resources :projects do
  resources :microposts
end
```

and the form.

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

------- Update 1 ---------

Projects Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user || :admin_user  , only: :destroy

  def index
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project Created"
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Project.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Project Deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end
end
```

------ Update 2 --------

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy
before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy


def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @micropost = @project.microposts.build
  #I cannot have them both defined at the same time so how do I go about this 
  @micropost = @project.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save
        flash[:success] = "Project Created"
        redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    Project.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Project Deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name,:category,:picture)
end

def correct_user
  @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @project.nil?
end
end
```

Comment: if you have not fixed it yet try to give a space `<%= form_for (@micropost), html: { multipart: true })`

Comment: Can you please post the contents of show action in projects controller

Comment: @Deepak that is now under update 1!

Comment: @7urkm3n I tried to add the space but that has created even more issues.

Comment: @Eltorero1992 just notice, you have a nested routes. try this one for testing purposes. `form_for ([Project.first, @micropost])` then let me know !

Comment: @7urkm3n I will do! ill let you know in a couple hours! Thanks a lot

Comment: @7urkm3n I tried what you suggested and did not work however I think I find a way around it but still getting lots of trouble please see update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue is,

In projects controller show action you are initializing `@project` but not  `@micropost` which will be `nil`

and I think you are rendering the same partial in `Projects#show`  which is trying to render form for `@micropost` which in this case is `nil`

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

It should be

```
<%= form_for(@project, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand what you mean, but would it be possible to initialize micropost by adding a line on Projects#show asking for it to load the he micropost for that particular project?

Comment: Also what if I refence it like <%= form_for(micropost.new, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %> what sort of implication might that have?

Comment: Yes, you can initialize the variable in project#show action

Comment: As per your second comment the problem with that approach is you can not reuse the `_form` partial

Comment: So I did what you said and initialize the micropost variable on project#show however now I'm getting a completely different error. See update 2. As I'm trying to have the option to build a post and also to show all posts for projects I'm getting this error "undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>"

Comment: Its because you are overriding `@micropost` with activerecord collection

Comment: In form for it should be either new instance or an saved record

Comment: If you also need paginated result change the variable name